# Is there anything like youtube-dl, but in pure jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

Is there anything like http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/
which will allow to get json of youtube movie,
get direct links to various format of videos,
even with username and password, to private yt movies?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but if you're still interested check out the project called node-youtube-dl. It allows you to download videos directly from YouTube and many other video providers.

If you're more interested only in the YouTube platform, I suggest you checking out node-ytdl. It is a youtube downloader written in Javascript. To be used with the command line. If you're looking to use it in your node program, check out, node-ytdl-core.

Links:

- https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl
- https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl
- https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core

Comment: node-youtube-dl has a dependency on the Python module youtube-dl. node-ytdl and node-ytdl-core do not (pure JS)